# Is the Hardy space $H^\infty$ closed under differentiation?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

** As it's been pointed out, the underlying matter of this question (that $f$ holomorphic and bounded does not imply $f'$ bounded) has been already answered in other post. However, here it's seen as a functional analysis question. Furthermore, the answers in the other post are merely a few counterexamples, and I feel that the abstract answers given here by @DavidC.Ullrich and @zhw. provide a more understanding explanation of the matter.

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic and bounded function, where $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ is the unit disk and $\mathbb{C}$ the complex numbers; i.e. let $f$ in the Hardy space $\mathcal{H}^\infty$.
Then is it true that $f'$ must be bounded too?

That is, is $\mathcal{H}^\infty$ closed under differentiation?

I've found some papers about the topic online but none of them clarifies this so I guess that I might be missing some point. Thank u for any help!

Comment: you have to use the Cauchy integral formula for expressing $f'(z)$ in term of $f(z)$

Comment: No. Consider something like $(1-z)^{1/2}$. Using Cauchy's estimates in the disk $D(z,1-|z|)$ shows that $|f'(z)|\le||f||_\infty/(1-|z|)$, and a slightly more sophisticated argument improves that to $||f||_\infty/(1-|z|^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've seen that $f'$ need not be bounded. Applying Cauchy's Estimates in the disk $D(z,1-|z|)$ shows that $$|f'(z)|\le\frac{||f||_\infty}{1-|z|}.$$Here's a simple example showing that that's best possible, at least up to a constant factor: Let $$f(z)=(1-z)^i\quad(|z|<1).$$To be specific, if $|z|<1$ then $1-z=re^{it}$ with $r>0$ and $-\pi/2<t<\pi/2$; define $f(z)=e^{-t+i\log(r)}$ and note that $|f(z)|\le e^{\pi/2}$. Then $$|f'(z)|=\frac1{1-|z|}\quad(0<z<1).$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Cauchy's estimate here. At least $$\lvert f'(z) \rvert \leq \frac1{2\pi}\int_{\lvert z \rvert=1} \left \lvert \frac{f(w)\mathrm{d}w}{(w-z)^2}\right \rvert$$ results in the tighter $$\lvert f'(z) \rvert \leq \frac{\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}}{1-\lvert z \rvert^2}.$$

Comment: If $|f|\le M$ in $D(z,r)$ then $|f'(z)|\le M/r$ (and similarly for higher derivatives).

Comment: Ah, $D(z,1-|z|)$ then and not $D(0,1-|z|)$.

Comment: @WimC Oops! Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I thought of was a "soft proof": Suppose $f \to f'$ maps $H^\infty$ to $H^\infty.$ By the closed graph theorem, this linear map is continuous. Thus there exists $C$ such that $\|f'\|_\infty \le C\|f\|_\infty$ for all $f\in H^\infty.$ The functions $z^n$ show this fails.

But it's easier to just note $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n^2$ is a counterexample.